# Getting raw input from user

Tags: python, raw-input

I am getting input from users via `raw_input` (using a `for` loop).

What code can I use to ensure that if a user presses only <kbd>Enter</kbd> it  keeps the default values (i.e. `raw_input` returns an empty string `''` when no value has been entered)?

So for the default values are in the form of variables:

```
age_years = 2       
cash_earned_last_year = 1000  
growth = 0.02
```

Comment: *"raw input returns an empty string when no value has been entered"* - that is correct. It is a pretty easy thing to check for, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Can you show more of your code so we can work out what you're actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you need to iterate over values inserted by user and replace with an empty string if the user type only Enter key.

```
def values_input():
    return raw_input("Please enter value or 'quit' to finish: ")

values = []
for code in iter(values_input, "quit"):
    if len(code) == 0:
        values +=['']
    else:
        values += [code]
print values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` to check if the user pressed only enter. As [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)
said, only <kbd>Enter</kbd> would set your input equal to empty string, that is, `''`.

```
if user_answer_1 == '':
    age_years = 2       
    cash_earned_last_year = 1000  
    growth = 0.02
```

If user is supposed to either press enter, or give numerous inputs, then you can use break to skip the rest of the questions if his first answer was <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
while True:

    user_age_answer = input('\nAge?') 

    if user_age_answer == '':
        age_years = 2       
        cash_earned_last_year = 1000  
        growth = 0.02
        # Skips the rest of the questions.
        break

    # Here go the rest of the questions.
    user_cash_answer = input('Cash?')

    # And then you do what you want with the answers.
    age_years = user_age_answer

    # This break is used to exit loop.
    break
```